# Pip with Anaconda: How to make pip install to activated environment site-packages folder?

Tags: pip, virtualenv, python-import, conda

I am trying to test a package that I have built and would like to see what a user with a new computer might experience when installing my package. I decided to simulate this by creating a new python environment using:

```
conda create --name testpython35 python=3.5
```

Then, when I activated that environment and did something like:

```
import pandas
```

I got no error, where I expected an `ImportError`.

How would I use `conda` and `pip` to install a totally clean python environment so that I can test my package?

Comment: You created a new environment but didn't install pandas in it.

Comment: That's right, I was expecting that doing an import would give me an error, but the import was successful.

Comment: Did you activate the newly created environment? Are you sure you are using the python from the new environment? Do you have the env variable `PYTHONPATH` set? Look at the output for: `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`